# How to get related model data in Django Admin panel?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

I am developing a product base table and my `product` table is related to `Informtion` table, it means a product can have information, but when i add product from admin panel, i am not getting information data there when i submit the product, Please let me know how i can get the `information` table fields in `product` add form in django admin panel.

Here is my `models.py file...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Information(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, related_name='product_info', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    number=models.IntegerField(default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

my `admin.py' file is this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from customer.models import *
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Product)
admin.site.register(Information)
```

when i am clicking on `add product` it's displaying there only `name`, `type` and i want to display the data from `information` table also, i want all fields when i click on `add product`

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class InformationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Information

class productAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [InformationInline]

admin.site.register(Product,productAdmin)
```

and remove the below line:

```
admin.site.register(Product)
```

Now restart the server and go into your admin and now you can see all the information table data and edit it.

Comment: Still getting only `Product` table data when i click on `add product`, but i want to add data from `information` table also...it's displaying only `name` ,`type` when i click on 'add product'.

Comment: this is the only way.. You must be doing some silly mistake..please check if your model name starts with capital letter.try editing the code with ProductAdmin instead of productAdmin

Comment: it's working perfect but it's giving me `add another customer profile` and i don't wana add more, please check this screenshot `https://prnt.sc/tvtsmm`

Comment: leave it black.. dont add it.. its simple

Comment: but i want to remove this field from there

Comment: could you please solve this issue also...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305665/how-to-display-foreignkey-table-data-in-django

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called `Inline`. Read more about here: [Django Admin Inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)