# How to display Foreignkey table Data in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have `Customer` and `CustomerProfile` models, and customer have some information in customerprofile model, i want to get the data from `CustomerProfile` models, Please let me know how i can get the data.

Here are my `models.py` file...

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Customer, default=None, related_name='product_info', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    number=models.IntegerField(default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my single customer `views.py` file..

```
def customer_info(request, name):
    customer=Customer.objects.get(name=name)
     context={'customer':customer}
     return render(request, 'customer/profile.html', context)
```

Here is my `profile.html` file..

```
<h1>{{customer.name}}</h1>
 <h1>{{customer.email}}</h1>
<h1>{{customer.mobile}}</h1>
<h1>{{ustomer.title}}</h1>
<h1>{{ustomer.number}}</h1>
```

I am unable to display the `title` and `number`, please let me know how i can display.

Please provide the solution for this one also, how i can Display first 2 and last 2 digit in integet and rest all values in ***

```
number=999121212188


def maskNumber(number):
    last_char = number[-2:]
    print(last_char)
    st= number[0:2]+"*******"+last_char
    return st

print(maskNumber(str(number)))
```

this code is working perfect but when i want to implement this with my `mobile` number, which is given in `Customer` models, and i want to display the `mobile` value on `profile.html` file..

Answer (score 1):

```
def customer_info(request, name):
    customer=Customer.objects.get(name=name)
    customer_profile=Customer_profile.objects.get(product = customer)
    context={'customer':customer,
              'customer_profile':customer_profile
             }
    return render(request, 'customer/profile.html', context)
```

Similarly in the html, change it

```
<h1>{{customer_profile.title}}</h1>
<h1>{{customer_profile.number}}</h1>
```

Comment: please provide me the answer of my edited question, how i will display mobile number first and last digit in numeric, rest all in **

Answer (score 1):

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(name="XYZ")
profiles = customer.customerprofile_set.all()
```

Note: profiles will be a list. To access the first profile, you access profiles[0] and so on.

More on Foreign Key - Many To One - relations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

And, yes, as suggested by Adam, ideally a relation between a customer profile and customer should be a One-To-One relation.

Answer (score 0):

You do it like so:

```
customer.customerprofile_set.all()
```

But in your case I think you better use a OneToOne field instead of ForeignKey

Comment: Because I guess every customer can have exactly one profile, right? In your code a customer can have a whole set of profiles.

Comment: @GCPBukalo also I guess you can't display the `title` and `number` bcs you made a typo in `customer` (you forgot the `c`)

Comment: A ForeignKey will establish a a One-To-Many Relation, that is one customer can have many profiles, however, a one to one relation will ensure there is only one profile for one customer.