# Displaying Foreignkey table Data in Django?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm a Django Beginner and I was dealing with same problem as in :([How to display Foreignkey table Data in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305665/how-to-display-foreignkey-table-data-in-django/73158323?noredirect=1#comment129213978_73158323))
but the solution to mine was pretty simple which left me to wonder HOW? And even after I got rid of the problem I've a query .

My Models were :

```
 class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
    cust_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)


class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
    salary = models.BigIntegerField()
    emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(to=Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    given_by = models.ForeignKey(to=Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bill = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

As you can see my Order model contains " assigned_to " so in HTML template I wrote it as :

```
{% for x in my_orders %}
<tr>
<td>{{ x.assigned_to }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and all I was getting a blank space I went to shell and get the queryset which showed it as "assigned_to_id" instead of "assigned_to". and then changing in HTML as :

```
{% for x in my_orders %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ x.assigned_to_id}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

worked for me.
**Why is that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you didn't set a return for the Employee Model.

You can do something like that to your Employee model.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
    salary = models.BigIntegerField()
    emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
       return f"self.name"
```

Then in your template you will receive the name. If you want to access any other field then you need to use the `_` as you used after the name of the field

```
   assigned_to_id
   assigned_to_name
   assigned_to_salary
   assigned_to_emp_id
```